# PowerShell Sync files between source and destination folders and replace the latest file in destination

Tags: powershell, synchronization

First of all, i am new in powershell and i had try to search any solution on internet, but at the end i just couldn't fix this problem. Can anyone explain what the problem and how to fix it?
Appreciate that if someone willing to help me.

```
#specific source and destination path
$f1path = 'E:\Folder1'
$f2path = 'E:\Folder2'


#Get all files from source and destination
$f1file = Get-ChildItem -path $f1path
$f2file = Get-ChildItem -path $f2path

$comparetime = compare-object -referenceobject $f1file -differenceobject $f2file -property name,lastwritetime | sort-object name

$comparetime | foreach{
    $copy2 =@{
         'path'= $_.InputObject.FullName
    }
    if ($_.Sideindicator -eq "<="){
    "copying"
    $copy2.destination = $f2path
    copy-item @copy -Force
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

And below are the displayed errors.

Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At E:\test.ps1:44 char:12

- ```
  copy-item @copy -Force
  ```
- ```
            ~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationExcept
    ion
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Power
    Shell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: You're creating a splatting hashtable in var `$copy2`, but use undefined `@copy` for the actual Copy-Item cmdlet.. Also, wouldn't using robocopy be a better approach?

Comment: Thx Theo, i was studied about the robocopy and found that the keyword /xo excluded older files is the thing that i wanted.